После установки виндовс-10 система не запускается
Установка виндовс-10 прошла успешно и после этого произошла автоматическая перезагрузка компьютера. Но после этого система не запускается. На 3 секунды появляется приветственная заставка виндовс-10 и после этого происходит сброс компьютера, как буд-то нажимают на кнопку сброса. После трёх таких циклов появляется сообщение белым текстом на синем фоне, что компьютеру необходимо восстановление. Что вероятнее всего может быть? Буду рад любой помощи.

Если на HDD система, то у тебя хард приехал, если на SSD , тогда БП возможно, но это вообще убитый БП должен быть, что бы не тянуть даже обычный запуск.

Дополню версию Евгения Ли. Встречался всего один раз с такой ситуацией. Источник проблемы был в одном интеловском чипсете системной платы. На Win7 плата функционировала без проблем. На WIn10 после обновления драйверов именно этого чипсета ось уходила в автоматический ребут.

Спасибо, а может ли ещё быть из-за недостаточного количества оперативной памяти? До этого на этом компьютере стояла 32-разрядная вин-10, а я теперь установил 64-разраядную. Но во время установки появилось предупреждение, что с 1,5 гигами оперативки лучше ставить 32-разрядную.

64-битная требуем минимум 2 гб. Но в нынешних реалиях для нормальной работы нужно 16 гб, 8 гб в самом крайнем случае. На картоху с 1.5 гб стоит попытаться поставить какой-нибудь облегченный линукс.
